# What is the closure property in this case

Tags: formal-languages

There is requirements specification which has certain **Completeness** properties:

1. No "To be done" phrases
2. No references to non-existing items
3. No missing items
4. No missing functions
5. No missing products

> The first two of these properties form a subset of the completeness
>   properties which are called "closure" properties.

I am trying to understand why is that? The only thing I can think of is that these "work" with the existing items and are known (I could count the number of TBDs or wrong references), while I cannot know whether something is missing.
Am I on the right track?

Comment: Are you on the right track to where?

Comment: @JohnDouma with my understanding..